# Indexing and Searching on scanned file

Tags: java, lucene

In my Java Project i have a requirement to scan different files(PDF,DOCX.. etc).

After scanning documents ,i need to search documents based on entered Keywords.

With Lucene we can index and search on files. When i scan files ,those will be saved as Images.Here is my doubt how to search on Images using some keywords

Keywords are not predefined.

Please help on this.

EDIT : When i enter Keywords, it should search all images which i have scanned and show the relevant file.

Comment: Kindly add the code you have tried. Also, give the output you are getting and what you require.

Comment: @JafferWilson , Iam asking for code examples. I will edit my question for Clarity

Comment: Have you looked at Apache Tika?